# visual studio c++ - не открываются заголовочные файлы

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Я не особо разбираюсь в c++, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что заголовочные файлы из стандартной библиотеки (stdio, conio, winsock2) не открываются[image]

Что с этим можно поделать? Сижу на Visual Studio 2017, Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: почитайте про `#include <file>`   и `#include "file"`, возможно в этом ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, получилось. В настройках проекта поставил версию Windows SDK с 8.1 на 10

Comment: Кажется или получилось?